# SOAP Services doesnt show XML data properly

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-web-api, soap

I am nOOb in SOAP Web Services and this is my first time that I did this staff. I have notice one mistake and I know that problem is in `DataTable` but have no idea how to change code to work as I expect. 
The problem is following. I create Web API project and create a basic Web API when user input ID it returns xml data of following `ID`. 
Once I run it I get successfull result:

[image: Web API]

And Here is my code:

```
 [HttpGet]
        [ResponseType(typeof(AKONTA))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAKONTA(string id)
        {
            AKONTA aKONTA = db.AKONTAS.Find(id);
            if (aKONTA == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Ne postoji A_KONTO pod tim rednim brojem");
            }

            return Ok(aKONTA);
        }
```

After I create same project and same logic but using SOAP Web Services, first I get all field from database and in the end of web page I get data.(check image below)

[image]

[image]

My question is How to avoid using `DataTable` and generate `XML` as I get in my Web API project ? 
I google it but can not find anything else, because I am not using `MSSQL` database, currently I use `Oracle` database.

```
[WebMethod]
        public DataTable GetAkontasById(int Id)
        {
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection
            {
                ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Akontas"].ConnectionString
            };
            conn.Open();
            OracleCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            string query = "Select * from AKONTAS where A_KONTO = '" + Id + "'";
            command.CommandText = query;
            OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dtusertables = new DataTable();
            dtusertables.Load(reader);
            if (null != reader && !reader.IsClosed)
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
            return dtusertables;
        }
```

**UPDATE**

Here is my XML of WEB API Project

```
<AKONTA xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AkontasWebApi">
<A_KONTO>515534</A_KONTO>
<BROJ i:nil="true"/>
<DAT_UNOS>2005-12-07T00:00:00</DAT_UNOS>
<DRZAVA i:nil="true"/>
<EMAIL i:nil="true"/>
<FAKS i:nil="true"/>
<INTERNET i:nil="true"/>
<KONTAKT i:nil="true"/>
<MB>4309080150003</MB>
<MJESTO i:nil="true"/>
<NAZIV>HANNY TR TUZLA</NAZIV>
<OPSTINA i:nil="true"/>
<PBROJ i:nil="true"/>
<PDVMB i:nil="true"/>
<PORESKI i:nil="true"/>
<SIFRA_RAD>30017</SIFRA_RAD>
<TELEFON i:nil="true"/>
<TRANSAKCIJ i:nil="true"/>
<ULICA i:nil="true"/>
<VRSTA_KLIJENTA i:nil="true"/>
</AKONTA>
```

Comment: What is wrong?  It just looks like you want to change the format of the results in the final view.

Comment: Sure, In the first part of page it display all column from table (picture 2) and in the end of xml file you can notice that display data (picture 3). 
I want to display only data in XML no  table field.

Comment: The xml contains an embedded schema and then the datatable at the end.  The schema gives the type of each column.  Not sure what options you used to add the schema.

Comment: I belive it's DataTable.

Comment: With or without embedded schema?

Comment: Without embedded schema

Comment: It looks like the xml has a schema.

Comment: Yes, It containt schema

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with the schema.  You just need to reformat the output.  If you do not want to display everything in the xml then parse only what you need and put into the view.

Comment: I only need  the last part, I dont need schema. unfortunately I dont use View, only .ASMX SOAP Web Services Project. 

<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<DocumentElement xmlns="">
<AKONTAS diffgr:id="AKONTAS1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<A_KONTO>515534</A_KONTO>
<NAZIV>HANNY TR TUZLA</NAZIV>
<SIFRA_RAD>30017</SIFRA_RAD>
<MB>4309080150003</MB>
<DAT_UNOS>2005-12-07T00:00:00+01:00</DAT_UNOS>
</AKONTAS>
</DocumentElement>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</DataTable>

Comment: What does your webapi xml look like?  I should be able to take the current xml and convert.

Comment: Just a second I will post XML example in my question

Comment: You have also the picture (Picture 1, fist one in the beggining) how my Web APi XML is look like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199620/discussion-between-xerror-and-jdweng).

Answer (score 0):

Use Xml Linq like code below which takes xml response and create new xml just like old api:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication131
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            XElement element = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "DocumentElement").FirstOrDefault();

            XElement newXml = (XElement)element.FirstNode; 

        }
    }

}
```